# Google Login on Angular - gapi is not defined error

Tags: angular, google-api, google-signin

I've implemented a Google Login on Angular 5 which works for the first-time login, but when the user is already logged in and they return to the site they get the error `gapi is not defined` in the Chrome Console. I'm pretty sure this is something to do with the Angular scope, as I do have the gapi variable declared in the login module as seen here:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { WmApiService } from '../wm-api.service';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

declare const gapi: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _wmapi: WmApiService, private router: Router) { }

  public auth2: any;
  userProfile: any;
  user: any;

  // Initalise Google Sign-On
  public googleInit() {
    gapi.load('auth2', () => {
      this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: '[clientid].apps.googleusercontent.com',
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        scope: 'profile email'
      });
      this.attachSignin(document.getElementById('googleBtn'));
    });
  }

  // Log user in via Google OAuth 2
  public attachSignin(element) {
    this.auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
      (googleUser) => {
        // Get profile from Google
        let profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();        
        // Save user to the API until changed
        this._wmapi.tempuser = profile.getName().match(/\(([^)]+)\)/)[1];
        this._wmapi.tempuseravatar = profile.getImageUrl();
        this._wmapi.tempuserfullname = profile.getName();
        this._wmapi.tempuseremail = profile.getEmail();
        // Log the user in
        this._wmapi.userloggedin = 1;
        // Redirect to dashboard
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      }, (error) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
        // To get auth token - googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        // To get user id - profile.getId();
      });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.googleInit();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I've made sure I've got the google api script in the index.html, so I'm not sure how I can get angular to understand that the user is logged in and not kick the user back to the login page when I navigate to the dashboard for example?

Comment: Did you add google client js in index.html
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>

Comment: Yeah added the script `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>` - that's the one I got direct from google on their tutorial for the google login

Comment: can you remove this `async defer` from your script tag

Comment: Mate you're a life saver thank you! That worked!